# NSAttributedString tail truncation in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, hashtag

I'm using [ContextLabel](https://github.com/michaelloistl/ContextLabel) to parse @ , # and URL's. This is the best solution i found, cause it sizes correctly and dont affect performance. It firstly parses string at input and than converts it to `NSAttributedString` and after this assigns it to `attributedText` property of `UILabel`. Everything works as expected, except tail truncation - it's very incorrect ( see pic below )

[image]

Where shall i start digging - is it wrong attributes on attributed string? Or label layout issue? Thanks!

Comment: Are you hard coding the width of that label?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I had this problem and fixed it by adding a `NSParagraphStyle` specifying the desired line break mode:

```
    //assuming myString is an NSMutableAttributedString
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail

    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: myString.mutableString.length)
    myString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: range)
```

See [Word wrap for NSMutableAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080942/word-wrap-for-nsmutableattributedstring) for further reference.

Answer (score 22):

Following also works irrespective of using AttributedText or normal text.
Make sure to add the below line ***after*** setting the AttributedText and font to the label:

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

Comment: You made my day! Thanks. Keyword - AFTER

Answer (score 1):

```
func htmlToAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString?
    {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do
        {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
            paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
            
            
            let content = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType:     NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:     String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
            
            content.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
                                   NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name:"Poppins-Medium",size:18),
                                   NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: (94.0/255.0), green: (90.0/255.0), blue: (90.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)],
                                  range: NSMakeRange(0, content.length))
            
            return content
        }
        catch
        {
            return nil
        }
    }
```